# How to copy a Hive external table to Readshift without using Data Pipeline

Tags: hive, amazon-redshift

I'd like to upload a Hive external table to AWS Redshift directly via command line. I don't want to use the Data Pipeline. Do I have to upload the table to S3 first and then copy it to Redshift? Is there any way to do it directly?

Comment: Do you have the external table already in S3?

Comment: No. I can easily upload the external table to S3. But I'm wondering if there's a way to upload to Redshift directly.

Comment: You can use SSH COPY to Redshift (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/loading-data-from-remote-hosts.html), but I think S3 option is easier

Answer (score 0):

You can load Redshift directly from remote hosts using SSH or, if you're using their EMR version of Hadoop, you can load directly from the HDFS file system.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html